# Clamp action distance in isometric grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance, isometric, clamp

I am currently working on a 2D isometric game where the player will be able to control different units, and interact through them.

I created a Scriptable Object called UnitType. Thanks to this system I can define an action range and a moving range, that is the maximum distance in cells that the player can move to or interact with.

The problem is I don't know how to implement this through code. This is what I want to achieve, using an action range of 2 cells for the demonstration.
[This is the goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5eJV.png)

With a friend of mine, we thought about calculating the linear equation of those 4 lines to check if the raycast hit was within them, but it's not working right with negative x.
[This is the current system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeF5C.png)

What would be the best practice ?

Thank you very much for your time and attention,

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: Can there be obstacles? Can actions be blocked by obstacles? Can actions bend around obstacles? What distance metric do you want? Max x/y?

Comment: Also, movement usually is done by pathfinding, while actions might need a system for line of sight, and these are different problems. You might also need to consider if you allow diagonal movement or not, and if these are more "expensive".

Answer (score 0):

Mousehit is a Unity GameObject that is the child of the character. Its positions is bound to the center of the tilemap cells thanks to mousePosition that is a script attached to the GameManager.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class Interact : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Sprite upperLeft, upperRight, midLeft, midRight, bottomLeft, bottomMid, bottomRight;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject mouseHit;
    public UnitType unitType;
    private GameObject gameManager;
    private CheckMousePosition mousePosition;
    private bool isInteracting, isAtGoodDistance;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private Tilemap tilemap;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;
    //private Transform mouseHit;
    void Start()
    {
        tilemap = GameObject.Find("Tilemap").GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        gameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager");
        mousePosition = gameManager.GetComponent<CheckMousePosition>();
        spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        isInteracting = false;
        mouseHit.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isInteracting)
        {
            mouseHit.SetActive(true);
            mouseHit.transform.position = new Vector3(mousePosition.tilemap.GetCellCenterLocal(mousePosition.cellPosition).x, mousePosition.tilemap.GetCellCenterLocal(mousePosition.cellPosition).y, 1);

           

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Interaction();
            }
        }

        if (isInteracting == false)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = null;
            mouseHit.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void InitInteraction()
    {
        isInteracting = true;
        transform.root.GetComponent<ContextualMenu>().CloseContextualMenu();
    }

    private void Interaction()
    {
        //When the player interacts, we cast a ray that will determine what he is interacting with.
        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            if (isInteracting)
            {
                isInteracting = false; //the player is no longer interacting.

                //If the player is interacting with a farmable cell using the worker.
                if (transform.root.name == "Worker"
                    && hit.collider.GetComponent<FarmableCell>() != null)
                {
                    CheckInteractionDistance();
                    //hit.collider.GetComponent<FarmableCell>().CheckIfFarmed();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckInteractionDistance()
    {
        if (mouseHit.transform.localPosition.y <= (-0.5 * (mouseHit.transform.localPosition.x) + unitType.actionDistance / 2)
            && mouseHit.transform.localPosition.x >= (-0.5 * (mouseHit.transform.localPosition.x) - unitType.actionDistance / 2)
            && mouseHit.transform.localPosition.x >= (0.5 * (mouseHit.transform.localPosition.x) - unitType.actionDistance / 2)
            && mouseHit.transform.localPosition.x <= (0.5 * (mouseHit.transform.localPosition.x) + unitType.actionDistance / 2))
        {
            Debug.Log("ok");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("not ok");
        }
    }
}
```